# How do I iterate through json data i grabbed from the web?

Tags: python, json

I am simply trying to iterate over a json data and print a person's name. I've tried looking up solutions on how people did this, but none of what I have tried has worked.

Python Code:

```
my_url = 'www.domain.com'
my_data = json.loads(requests.get(my_url).text)

# I know in for loop I can go into people and go into info. But i'd like how to know how to do it by just going into people

for person in my_data['people']:
    print(person['info']['name'])
```

---

Json

```
{
    "amt_people": 3,
    "people": {
        "1": {
            "info": {
                "name": "Mike"
            }
        },

        "2": {
            "info": {
                "name": "Paul"
            }
        },

        "3": {
            "info": {
                "name": "Sarah"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people object is not a list but a dictionary you cannot iterate over a dictionary like this. This should work.

```
my_url = 'www.domain.com'
my_data = json.loads(requests.get(my_url).text)
for id , person in my_data['people'].items():
    print(person['info']['name'])
```